# jQuery drag events not working the same way in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, drag

I am trying to make android pattern lock screen for web using jQuery. [Please find the fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/ptp24mm0/1/)

I made a similar sample file and it worked perfectly. [Please find its fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/hepbob75/6/)

I used `$(".button").on("mousedown", function (event){...}` to detect the start of drag and `$(document).bind("mousemove", function(event) { ... }` to detect ongoing dragging.

Is my understanding of these functions is wrong somewhere? Can this problem be solved in someway?
Any hint on why the lines not working the way they are supposed to?

Please let me know if any further is necessary.

Any further suggestions to the problem are most welcome.

This is working far differently in Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 and Frefox Version 30. Any reason for this?